# "Create App" button is missing on a verified developer profile

Tags: facebook-apps

I used to be able to create facebook apps a few months ago using my personal profile. Now I got back to development again but unable to create any apps for a simple reason that the page https://developers.facebook.com/apps does not have a Create App button any more.

My account is verified, I had activated the facebook developer app before (even though I do not see in my app list for some reason now), I am logged in as a person, not as a page admin and I have created apps before using exact the same account.

What could be wrong?

Comment: This is a question for Facebook support, not SO.

Comment: Looking for facebook support on the developer app page brought me here. This page: https://developers.facebook.com/support/ "Ask for help" link.

Comment: Yes, but from the very same paragraph: `making it one of the best places for you to get help with your **programming questions**.` Questions which are about FB Policy or specific to your account are not on topic here

Comment: I don't think we are discussing what the question has asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known problem that looks about consistency on developer data.

The solution I posted here [Facebook - Unable to create an app](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15152732/facebook-unable-to-create-an-app)

go to https://developers.facebook.com/setup

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting with this issue for hours!  I think it happened because I haven't created an app since facebook transitioned to the app center.  Going directly to https://developers.facebook.com/setup fixed my issue!